# Linux Mint 16 on HP Pavilion dv6 laptop - power management doesn't work

Tags: laptop, linux-mint, power-management, hp-pavilion

I installed **Linux Mint 16** on my HP Pavilion dv6 laptop.

On Linux, my laptop always seems to be under load (fan spins at full speed etc.)

Is there any power management tool / driver that could help me to identify the cause of this apparently high CPU usage when running Mint? Something like Laptop Power Plan Assistant For Windows 7 would be ideal.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you finally use?

Answer (score 0):

TLP is a power management tool for Linux Mint

You can find some of the details here http://www.noobslab.com/2013/07/how-to-improve-laptop-power-management.html

It is command line tool and does not contain GUI so it may not be as friendly as the Windows 7 Laptop Power plan Assistant but installation even with default settings is quite effective.

Following site provides installation and configuration details https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TLP